# I am stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am editing a reporting tool on Excel with Vba and i created a new pivot table in another worksheet and want to use the findings of this pivot table to edit another worksheet.but i am now stuck in a loop

```
  Check the number of division for the LM
Divisions_Count.Select
CntRow = 2
    Do While Divisions_Count.Cells(CntRow, 1).Value <> "Grand Total"
        If Details.Cells(DetRow, 1).Value = Divisions_Count.Cells(CntRow, 1).Value Then
            Nb_Div = Divisions_Count.Cells(CntRow, 2).Value

        Else
            CntRow = CntRow + 1
        End If
    Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Do While Divisions_Count.Cells(CntRow, 1).Value <> "Grand Total"
        If Details.Cells(DetRow, 1).Value = Divisions_Count.Cells(CntRow, 1).Value Then
            Nb_Div = Divisions_Count.Cells(CntRow, 2).Value
        End If
        CntRow = CntRow + 1
Loop
```

*(Untested)*